# What is the best controller setup in Killzone 2?

Tags: controllers, killzone-2

I recently purchased *Killzone 2* (PS3) and I'm a bit new to console gaming, especially FPS. I have trouble with aiming and moving/turning sideways. The sensitivity of the right thumb stick doesn't fit very well on my finger. I tried changing the sensitivity, but the result was not helpful. I would like to know if there's a better way of configuring these controller settings.

**Update**: The latest update (patch) added the ‘**High Precision**’ setting in the controller options. It gives some smooth moving capabilities but still I need to improve my aiming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest patch, then try the "High Precision" mode, as described here: https://kotaku.com/how-killzone-2s-patch-can-change-your-controls-5271701

> When this option is switched on, it makes the analog sticks more responsive to small movements. Turned off, the controls behave exactly as they did before the patch. It's not a radical overhaul of the control system, so the layout and the ‘weight' of the controls remain the same.
>
> Still, a lot of us here at Guerrilla really enjoy the new High Precision option, so we've decided to switch it on by default for new players. Existing Killzone 2 players will have the option turned off by default after patching – we wouldn't want to force a sudden change to the controls on you!

Comment: Although I'm not sure if game patches can be downloaded while PSN is down... you might have to wait.

Comment: Does it automatically prompts to download the patch, I ask this because I got a prompt saying have to download some new changes although I thought that it is because of the recent firmware update in PS3.

Answer (score 0):

I am used to the PS3 controller and still had difficulty aiming in Killzone 2 when I first started playing.  Change the default controller layout in the settings menu. The default is to zoom with R3 and fire with R1 but you will find it easier to zoom with L1 and fire with R1. I believe it was the second choice (I traded it in for KZ3 so I couldn't tell you for certain).